# Python: "split()" ignores "\n"

Tags: python

I have a text file `myfile.txt`. The first line of the file is `foo bar`. I want to split this line into the two respective words. Here is my code:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    words = line.split(' ')
    word1 = words[0]
    word2 = words[1]
    print words
    print word1
    print word2
```

And the output is:

```
['foo', 'bar\n']
foo
bar
```

My question is, why does `split()` seem to eliminate the `\n` from the second word, even though I have only asked to split based on the whitespace character?

Comment: `why does split() seem to eliminate the \n from the second word`. It actually, didnt

Comment: It is not eliminating it obviously, you can see it in the list.

Comment: `print line` wouldn't show a list - I suspect that's the output from `print words`... and `word2` will still have the trailing `\n`... You're probably just missing the fact that when you print it, you'll get a blank line after it.... try `print repr(word2)` instead

Answer (score 5):

`split()` does not eliminate the `\n`. What happens is that `print` simply prints it out as a newline.

Use `repr()` to see it:

```
In [3]: word2 = 'bar\n'

In [4]: print word2
bar


In [5]: print repr(word2)
'bar\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does split() seem to eliminate the \n from the second word, even though I have only asked to split based on the whitespace character?

In fact that is not what is happening. The call to `split(' ')` does not remove the `'\n'`.

```
>>> line = 'foo bar\n'
>>> line
'foo bar\n'
>>> line.split(' ')
['foo', 'bar\n']
>>> line.split(' ')[1]
'bar\n'
>>>>
```

When you print `'bar\n'` the `\n` is interpreted as a newline.

```
>>> print line.split(' ')[0]
foo
>>> print line.split(' ')[1]
bar

>>>
```

Notice that there is an extra line after `bar`, but not after `foo`.

Comment: The asker didn't say the call to ``split(' ')`` removed the ``'\n'``. He asked why it seemed to be eliminated (i.e. printing *words* versus printing *word2*).

Comment: @tsroten In fact the question asked was: *Why does split() seem to eliminate the \n from the second word, even though I have only asked to split based on the whitespace character?*

Comment: You said *What you report is not correct.* However, he reported that it seemed to be eliminated. In other words he was speaking of the apparent discrepancy between printing *words* and *word2*.

Comment: @tsroten You know that. I know that. But the asker did not. Both NPE and I interpreted the question the same way. And I don't really think I corrected anything. Perhaps i just needed to be even clearer about what the asker's mis-conception was.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I was being a bit picky. Sorry about that.